# Java toString() not printing the correct variable

Tags: java, tostring, println

I have a class like this in Java:

```
public class Wrapper {
    public static List<Type> list;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "List: " + this.list;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Wrapper w = new Wrapper();
        System.out.println(w);
    }
}
```

and a class like this:

```
public class Type {
    private static String name;

    public Type(String n) {
        this.name = n;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

Instead of getting the name of each item, I get the name of the last item for each item in the array.  Any suggestions?

Comment: try remove that `static` word for the variable name and try it again ;)

Comment: I would agree that this is a duplicate, but to be fair, I don't think that I would've found that answer from Googling/searching on SO, as I thought this was a problem of toString...

Comment: in class `Type` `private static String name;` should be `private String name`. its not a static field (or shouldn't be the way you are using it in the constructor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in your `Type` class you are marking your `name` as `static` so when printing `type.toString()` you always have only one value.
And if you want to print all member of your list, use:

```
for(Type t : list){
   System.out.print(t.toString());
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  This works.  Thank you also to @kucing_terbang for the comment!   I'll accept this when I can.

Comment: He is trying to return from toString(), not print to the console.

Comment: If this is your answer, please mark it as correct answer

Comment: Yes I know and I know he understand what I mean.

Comment: +1. Note that good IDEs and compilers emit a warning for this code, since `this.name` is misleading when `name` is static.

Comment: @user1947561 please read about static, agains. You are using incorrect way of static.

Answer (score -1):

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    String s = "";
    for(Type t : list) {
        s += t;
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: add some text with answer to explain how your answer help OP or others in solving issue